# How to set a vertical border in between two divs?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm having a problem with borders in between two `divs` and so I've tried a couple of different pieces of code to see if it gives me what I need; for example, I tried using a new `<div >` in between the `divs` I want the vertical border to be in, but I don't think I'm inputting the information correctly. I understand that you have to also add code to your CSS sheet but wwhat should it look like exactly? What's the proper way?

Taking this piece of code into consideration: How would I go by adding a vertical line in between the `#content` and the `#sidebar`? You could say that its a vertical line that separates both elements if it had text.

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            header content here
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            main content here
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
            sidebar content here
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            footer content here
        </div>

    </div>
```

=============CSS============

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#header {

}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 340px;

}

footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here's an image as to how this code would look in text. [Example with text of code given above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Fec.png)

So basically, I'm trying to figure out how to add a border in between the left paragraph and the right paragraph.

I hope its understandable and my question is clear enough.

Thanks,

Comment: There's a cool CSS property called border-left and border-right, check it out and solve your problem: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-left.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-left-style: solid;` in your #sidebar or using `border-right-style: solid;` in your #content

Comment: Adding border-left-style: solid; to #sidebar made the sidebar go under the content instead of it being on the side. The same thing with border-right-style: solid; but I decided to use border-right-style: solid; in my #content and change the width of my #sidebar and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea but I'm not sure how well it will work. Put 'first name' input down to the 'Access now' button as one div and define a border-left css property like so:

```
`.mydiv{
border-left: thick double #777;
}`
```